# Get HTTP status code descriptions in ASP.Net Core

Tags: asp.net, .net-core

In previous versions of ASP.Net, we could retrieve the description of a HTTP status code in a few ways as shown here:

[Get description for HTTP status code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542870/get-description-for-http-status-code)

Is there something similar to `HttpWorkerRequest.GetStatusDescription` in ASP.Net Core?

Comment: Do you have a `HttpResponseMessage`? You can use the `ReasonPhrase` property of it, it seems. It does use `HttpStatusDescription` internally, but sadly that class is not `public`.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.ReasonPhrases.GetReasonPhrase(int statusCode)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.webutilities.reasonphrases.getreasonphrase?view=aspnetcore-2.2) (which can be got from the [Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities package in NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities/) if not already referenced in your project transiently by a package like `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`):

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities;

int statusCode = 404;
string reasonPhrase = ReasonPhrases.GetReasonPhrase(statusCode);
```

Comment: What is the value of `reasonPhrase`?

Comment: In this case for 404 it would be `"Not Found"`. For `405` it would be `"Method Not Allowed"` etc.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that this method is in a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities/), and is not part of Net Core itself.

Comment: It's part of asp.net 5.0, no need for Nuget.

Comment: Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities has been marked as deprecated.

Comment: Version 2.2.0 has, but after that version it is included in the ASP.NET Core shared framework https://stackoverflow.com/a/70847316/1064169. Also from looking at NuGet, a new version for 8.0.0 will ship in November 2023 with .NET 8 RTM.

Answer (score 15):

This is close enough for my needs:

```
var statusCode = httpContext.Response.StatusCode
var description = ((HttpStatusCode)statusCode).ToString(); // 404 -> "NotFound"
```

Comment: Not a real solution - you could have done this in ASP.Net, it doesn't give you a user-friendly message.

Comment: @ChrisPeacock And that is why I didn't select this as the answer. If someone posts something better, then I will certainly accept it.

Comment: I've resorted to copying the code from ASP.Net's HttpWorkerRequest.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using a NuGet or splicing a string, here's a simple implementation. These descriptions should match the source of HttpWorkerRequest.

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Descriptions for Http Status Code
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="code"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string GetHttpStatusDescription(int code)
        {
            switch (code)
            {
                case 100: return "Continue";
                case 101: return "Switching Protocols";
                case 102: return "Processing";
                case 200: return "OK";
                case 201: return "Created";
                case 202: return "Accepted";
                case 203: return "Non-Authoritative Information";
                case 204: return "No Content";
                case 205: return "Reset Content";
                case 206: return "Partial Content";
                case 207: return "Multi-Status";
                case 300: return "Multiple Choices";
                case 301: return "Moved Permanently";
                case 302: return "Found";
                case 303: return "See Other";
                case 304: return "Not Modified";
                case 305: return "Use Proxy";
                case 307: return "Temporary Redirect";
                case 400: return "Bad Request";
                case 401: return "Unauthorized";
                case 402: return "Payment Required";
                case 403: return "Forbidden";
                case 404: return "Not Found";
                case 405: return "Method Not Allowed";
                case 406: return "Not Acceptable";
                case 407: return "Proxy Authentication Required";
                case 408: return "Request Timeout";
                case 409: return "Conflict";
                case 410: return "Gone";
                case 411: return "Length Required";
                case 412: return "Precondition Failed";
                case 413: return "Request Entity Too Large";
                case 414: return "Request-Uri Too Long";
                case 415: return "Unsupported Media Type";
                case 416: return "Requested Range Not Satisfiable";
                case 417: return "Expectation Failed";
                case 422: return "Unprocessable Entity";
                case 423: return "Locked";
                case 424: return "Failed Dependency";
                case 500: return "Internal Server Error";
                case 501: return "Not Implemented";
                case 502: return "Bad Gateway";
                case 503: return "Service Unavailable";
                case 504: return "Gateway Timeout";
                case 505: return "Http Version Not Supported";
                case 507: return "Insufficient Storage";
            }
            return "";
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Improving on the previous answer, you could split `HttpStatusCode` enum name with spaces, e.g.:

```csharp
public string GetStatusReason(int statusCode)
{
    var key = ((HttpStatusCode) statusCode).ToString();

    return string.Concat(
        key.Select((c, i) =>
            char.IsUpper(c) && i > 0
                ? " " + c.ToString()
                : c.ToString()
        )
    );
}
```

Or if you prefer regular expressions:

```csharp
public string GetStatusReason(int statusCode)
{
    var key = ((HttpStatusCode) statusCode).ToString();
    return Regex.Replace(key, "(\\B[A-Z])", " $1");
}
```

Also you can simplify it to just this:

```csharp
public string GetStatusReason(HttpStatusCode statusCode)
{
    var key = statusCode.ToString();
    return Regex.Replace(key, "(\\B[A-Z])", " $1");
}
```

Looking at the enum key names they seem to be pretty reasonably named so most, if not all, status codes should yield acceptable reason messages.

Comment: The only issue with this is status code 200 (OK), which gets converted to `"O K"` (ie. the characters O and K, with a space inbetween).

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
int code = 404;
string statusText = Enum.GetName(typeof(HttpStatusCode), code);
```

Comment: This would return "NotFound"; the expected result would be "Not Found".

Answer (score 0):

if response is HttpResponseMessage from HttpClient...

```
ReasonPhrases.GetReasonPhrase((int)response.StatusCode))
```