# Returning custom objects with asp.net core api errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using asp.net core 2.1, I need to emulate some existing behavior when returning errors in an api whereby the response includes a custom object:

```
return this.BadRequest(
    new ApiError
    {
        // The corresponding integer response code.
        Status = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest,
        // The matching short text code.
        Code = "BadRequest",
        // A detailed context specific message.
        Message = "Some message"
    });
```

My question is, asp.net core brought the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.StatusCodes` class with integer fields that indicate the response codes, however the field names are not something I want to expose for example by `Code = nameof(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)`.

What is the modern means to generate the response description `BadRequest` in this case without magic strings?

I could use `System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest` and `nameof(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)` however that seems to ignore newer conventions?

I am not trying to convert return types, the controller and action signatures are already well defined. I want to ensure I am using a concise means to accommodate existing consumers that expect an object with the fields required, and I want to do this without magic strings or multiple unrelated classes if possible.

I imagine the use case is more common than not and more elaborate facility exists to accomplish this?

Comment: Why would it be common to have a property that says 400 Bad Request when the HTTP status code tells you that?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you mean. The `BadRequest` function sets the status code and status text appropriately. The reason Microsoft moved to `StatusCodes` was precisely to move away from hard-coding things like this. Now everyone's wondering how to hard-code things like this :). You could just call `ToString` on the `HttpStatusCode` as well. See [Get HTTP status code descriptions in ASP.Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43783402)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, your comment above answers your first comment. I am required to an object than implements the fields described, this is distinct from the response code in semantics. The handlers in the consumer code utilize the object's properties. I am looking for a concise way to accommodate it. I am not trying to convert `HttpResponseMessage` to `IActionResult`, that is not related.

Comment: @HereticMonkey The more I look at this, I continue to arrive at the same conclusion. I am going to look into accommodating the native functionality in the consuming code.